# Pandas if any n of m conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

Example.

Let's say I have dataframe with several columns and I want to select rows that match all 4 conditions, I would write:

```
condition = (df['A'] < 10) & (df['B'] < 10) & (df['C'] < 10) & (df['D'] < 10)
df.loc[condition]
```

Contrary to that if I want to select rows that match any of 4 conditions I would write:

```
condition = (df['A'] < 10) | (df['B'] < 10) | (df['C'] < 10) | (df['D'] < 10)
df.loc[condition]
```

Now, what if I want to select rows that match any two of those 4 conditions? That would be rows that match any combination of either columns (A and B), (A and C), (A and D), (B and C) or (C and D). It is obvious that I can write complex condition with all those combinations:

```
condition = ((df['A'] < 10) & (df['B'] < 10)) |\
            ((df['A'] < 10) & (df['C'] < 10)) |\
            ((df['A'] < 10) & (df['D'] < 10)) |\
            ((df['B'] < 10) & (df['C'] < 10)) |\
            ((df['C'] < 10) & (df['D'] < 10))
df.loc[condition]
```

But if there is 50 columns and I want to match any 20 columns of those 50, that would become impossible to list all possible combinations into condition. Is there a way to do that somehow better?

Comment: So you basically want at least two columns that are less than 10, right?

Comment: Yes, but 10 is here just example. Conditions can be different between columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `True == 1` and `False == 0` you can find rows that satisfy atleast N conditions by checking the sum. Series have most of the basic comparisons as attributes so you could make a single condition list with a variety of checks and then use `getattr` to make it tidy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, (5,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

---

```
# can check `eq`, `lt`, `le`, `gt`, `ge`, `isin`
cond_list = [('A', 'lt', 10), ('B', 'ge', 10), ('D', 'eq', 4), 
             ('C', 'isin', [2, 4, 6])]
df_c = pd.concat([getattr(df[col], attr)(val).astype(int) 
                  for col,attr,val in cond_list], axis=1)
#   A  B  D  C
#0  0  0  0  1
#1  0  1  0  0
#2  1  1  0  0
#3  1  1  0  0
#4  0  1  0  1

# Each row satisfies this many conditions
df_c.sum(1)
#0    1
#1    1
#2    2
#3    2
#4    2
#dtype: int64

#Select those that satisfy at least 2.
df[df_c.sum(1).ge(2)]
#    A   B   C   D
#2   0  17  15   9
#3   0  14   0  15
#4  19  14   4   0
```

---

If you need some more complicated comparisons that aren't possible with `.getattr` then you can write them out yourself and concat that list of Series.

```
df_c = pd.concat([df['A'].lt(10), df['B'].ge(10), df['D'].eq(4), 
                  df['C'].isin([2,4,6])], 
                 axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: this only works if you have homogenous conditions, what if you have `gt` and `eq` in the mix? can you parametrize the condition too?

Comment: This will help! If it possible to adjust for Yuca's comment, then will be even better.

Comment: @IvanToman Yes, so long as they are mostly basic checks (==, <, <=, >, >= and `isin`) you can use my method with `getattr` to make this very compact.

Comment: beautiful answer, great job :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method using `itertools.combinations`, so we can get all necessary combinations of our conditions. Then we check the "amount" of time condition1 & condition2 are `True`:

```
# test dataframe
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(10,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print(df)

    A   B   C   D   E
0   9   4  15   0  17
1  16  17   8   9   0
2  10   8   4  19  16
3   4  15  11  11   1
4   8   4  14  17  19
5  13   5  13  19  13
6  12   1   4  18  13
7  11  10   9  15  18
8  16   7  11  17  14
9   7  11   1   0  12
```

```
from itertools import combinations

conditions = [(df['A'] < 10), (df['B'] < 15), (df['C'] >= 5), (df['D'] <= 9)]
mask = pd.concat([x&y for x, y in combinations(conditions, 2)], axis=1).sum(axis=1).ge(2)

df[mask]

   A   B   C   D   E
0  9   4  15   0  17
4  8   4  14  17  19
9  7  11   1   0  12
```